# Using filter_if to filter based on a criteria

Tags: r, date, if-statement, filter

I am trying to filter a dataframe based on the column "type" and apply a filter criteria on "Date" if "type" matches. Here is an example:

```
df <- tibble(type = c("A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","C","C","C","C"),
           Date = ymd(c(20190101,20190105,20190110,20191231,20190530,20190630,20190730,20180630,20190730,20190112,20191230,20181215)))

    A_date <- c(ymd(2019-01-05),ymd(2019-12-31))
    B_date <- c(ymd(2019-05-30),ymd(2019-07-30))
    C_date <- c(ymd(2019-01-01),ymd(2019-12-15))

df
# A tibble: 12 x 2
   type  Date      
   <chr> <date>    
 1 A     2019-01-01
 2 A     2019-01-05
 3 A     2019-01-10
 4 A     2019-12-31
 5 B     2019-05-30
 6 B     2019-06-30
 7 B     2019-07-30
 8 B     2018-06-30
 9 C     2019-07-30
10 C     2019-01-12
11 C     2019-12-30
12 C     2018-12-15
```

I want to apply a filter such that if type is "A", then filter for all rows with type "A" with Date between A_date, and do the same for "B" and "C". Such that the resulting dataframe would be:

```
# A tibble: 8 x 2
   type  Date      
   <chr> <date>    
 1 A     2019-01-05
 2 A     2019-01-10
 3 A     2019-12-31
 4 B     2019-05-30
 5 B     2019-06-30
 6 B     2019-07-30
 7 C     2019-07-30
 8 C     2019-01-12
```

Is it possible to do this with tidyverse's "filter_if"? If not, is there any other solutions?

Comment: You can do it with plain filter if you only have a few types. You just want to make a few logical statements within filter such as `(type == "A" & between(Date, start, end)) | (type == "B" & between(Date, start, end) | ...`.

Comment: It might be too troublesome to type all those filter with more "type"s... thanks though :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you put start and end dates of each dataframe, you could do this easily by joining and filtering.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

ref <- data.frame(type= c('A', 'B', 'C'), start = ymd(c('2019-01-05', '2019-05-30', 
     '2019-01-01')), end = ymd(c('2019-12-31', '2019-07-30', '2019-12-15')))


df %>%
  left_join(ref, by  ='type') %>%
  filter(Date >= start & Date <= end) %>%
  select(type, Date)
```

and similarly in base R :

```
subset(merge(df, ref), Date >= start & Date <= end)
```